# code without log messages

Tags: java, logging

From time to time I come across a class where a bigger part of code are logging calls.
e.g.

```
public init(Config config) {
  logger.info("Configuring ...");

  if (config.hasInitInterval()) {
    initInterval = config.getInitInterval();
    logger.info("Set initInterval to " + initInterval);
  }
  ...
  try {
    logger.info("Updating access points " + config.getAccessPoints());
    updateAccessPoints(config.getAccessPoints())      
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    logger.warn("Init failed due to ", e);
  }
  ...
  if (logger.isDebugEnabled ()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < config.getModifiers().size(); i++) {
       try {
         isValidModifier(config.getModifiers().get(i));
       } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Wrong modifier: " config.getModifiers().get(i));
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When a class is not formatted well plus contains comments, it's hard to read the code.
I used proxy pattern to partially improve it but it's suitable only to log something before or after a call of method.

What are the best practices to separate functionality from logging?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Chain of Responsibility Patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)? This might solve parts of your problem.

Comment: @Turing85 can you be more specific or can you give me an example how to use the pattern?

Comment: check the link. The code example is actually a logger. I don't know how i could be more specific.

Comment: It's misunderstanding. The logger is instance of log4j. I don't think an example of logger in your link somehow can help because I am satisfied with log4j. I am not satisfied with structure of code in my example.